# How to make geom_abline show_guide line types show up in legend correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
set.seed(586)
data<-data.frame(x=sort(runif(20)),y=sort((rnorm(1)*1:20*.234)),grp=factor(sample(c(0,1),20,replace = T)))

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, shape=grp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_shape_manual("PT Status",
                     values=c(1,3),
                     breaks=c(0,1),
                     labels=c("No","Yes"))+
  scale_x_continuous("My x") +
  scale_y_continuous("My y")+
  geom_abline(intercept=.12, slope=.98,linetype=1,show_guide = TRUE)+     
  geom_abline(intercept=.05, slope=(-.3+.98),linetype=3,show_guide = TRUE)+
 theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Lines look right, and I like how the lines are integrated into the legend. But obviously in my code I'm not specifying what data go to which abline. Is there a way to simply indicate this in the `geom_abline` code, or some other way to recode it to make it so that the first one is solid and the second is dashed, in terms of the legend?

Using @Jorans suggestion I created

```
smDf<-data.frame(intercept=c(.12,.05),slope=c(.98, (-.3+.98)),linetype=factor(c(1,3)))
```

Then the new code is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, shape=grp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_shape_manual("PT Status",
                     values=c(1,3),
                     breaks=c(0,1),
                     labels=c("No","Yes"))+
  scale_x_continuous("My x") +
  scale_y_continuous("My y")+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, linetype=linetype), data=smDf, show_guide = TRUE)
```

Which gives me:

[image]

So now how do I integrate these two?

Comment: Put `slope`, `intercept` and `linetype` into a data frame and map those aesthetics in a single `geom_abline` call.

Comment: Thanks @joran . I did this but now I have the annoying two-legend-issue. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be better documented, I think, but you basically need to give ggplot manual scales of the same basic structure for them to be merged:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = data,aes(x=x, y=y, shape=grp)) +
    geom_abline(aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, linetype=linetype), data=smDf,show_guide = TRUE) +
    theme_classic() +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "PT Status",
                       values=c(1,3),
                       breaks=c(0,1),
                       labels=c("No","Yes"))+
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "PT Status",
                          values=c(1,3),
                          labels=c("No","Yes"))+
    scale_x_continuous("My x") +
    scale_y_continuous("My y")
```

Comment: I assumed since I didn't use `geom_line`, I wouldn't be able to fix it with `scale_linetype_manual`. I should have tried that though. Thank you!