# Add horizontal lines to stacked barplot in ggplot2 in R, and show in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend, legend-properties

I have a stacked barplot, something like the example below.

I want to add one or two sets of horizontal lines (specifying colour and line type) across each bar, at different values for each bar, and add these to the legend.

```
Titanic.df <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

Titanic.ag <- aggregate( Freq ~ Sex + Class + Age, data=Titanic.df, sum, subset = Survived == "Yes")

bars <- rep(c(0.5, NA, 0.7, NA, 0.6, NA, 0.9, NA), 2)

ggplot(Titanic.ag, aes(x = Class, y = Freq, fill = Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(~Age) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = bars, ymin = bars, ymax = bars,  col = "Ref1")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkblue") ) + 
  labs(col = "Reference",
       fill= "",
       y = "Proportion",
       x = "Class")
```

[image: titanic stacked bar plot with horizontal lines]

I have tried using geom_errorbar() as suggested on several questions, but I am stuck with two things:

If I add a vector of values for the error bars, then ggplot expects the same length as in the dataframe (eg 16 in Titanic.ag), but there are only 8 bars as they are stacked. This is why I have used NAs in `bars` above.
Is there an alternative?

More importantly, I want to control colour and line type, but if I add these to geom_bar(), I lose my legend. e.g.

```
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = bars, ymin=bars, ymax=bars,  col = "Ref1"), col = "red", linetype = 2)
```

Is geom_segment() an alternative?

Edited typos, clarified different values of horziontal lines.

Comment: geom_abline(slope=0,intercept=yournumber, col= "yourcolor" , lty=2) does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above doesn't produce a legend. It does change the linetype and colour, but I also showed this in my original question. After some searching I've found a way to add a legend, so I've posted here.

```
library(ggplot2)

Titanic.df <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

Titanic.ag <- aggregate( Freq ~ Sex + Class + Age, data=Titanic.df, sum, subset = Survived == "Yes")

bars <- rep(c(0.5, NA, 0.7, NA, 0.6, NA, 0.9, NA), 2)

ggplot(Titanic.ag, aes(x = Class, y = Freq, fill = Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(~Age) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = bars, ymin = bars, ymax = bars,  col = "Ref1"), linetype = 2, size = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkblue") ) + 

  scale_colour_manual(name='', values=c("Ref1" = "darkred"), guide ="legend") +
  guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=2), title = "Reference")) + 

  labs(fill= "",
       y = "Proportion",
       x = "Class")
```

This can be adapted to add a further geom_errorbar().

I still get the warning due to the workaround with the the NAs in the `geom_errorbar()` vector for `y`, `ymin` and `ymax`, this gets more complicated with more facets, but it works.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not completely sure that you need this but. Individual `geom_abline` calls let you customize easily as you wish each line.

```
ggplot(Titanic.ag, aes(x = Class, y = Freq, fill = Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(~Age) +
  geom_abline(slope=0, intercept=0.5,  col = "red",lty=2) +
  geom_abline(slope=0, intercept=0.75,  col = "lightblue",lty=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkblue") ) + 
  labs(col = "Reference",
       fill= "",
       y = "Proportion",
       x = "Class")
```

Produces this plot

[image]

Also, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925656/how-to-make-geom-abline-show-guide-line-types-show-up-in-legend-correctly) could help with the labels.

**UPDATE**

Ok, Now I understood...A quick approximation with the same approach would be to use more than one bars vector and error bar call. It's a bit exhausting but might work and a data.frame might not work because you want each bar to be custom several times. Also, take into account that NAs are removed so they are not working as one would like to...Maybe using a number higher than 1 and adjusting the ylim to 1 so they won't show

```
bars1 <- rep(c(0.5, NA, 0.7, NA, 0.6, NA, 0.9, NA), 2)
bars2 <- rep(c(NA, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, 0.5), 2)
bars3 <- rep(c(0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1), 2)

ggplot(Titanic.ag, aes(x = Class, y = Freq, fill = Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(~Age) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y = bars1, ymin = bars1, ymax = bars1), color="Orange",lty=2) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=bars2,ymin=bars2,ymax=bars2),color="White",lty=2)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=bars3,ymin=bars3,ymax=bars3),color="Purple",lty=2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkblue") ) + 
  labs(col = "Reference",
       fill= "",
       y = "Proportion",
       x = "Class")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify, I need different values for each horizontal line on each bar. eg here with just two: `bars <- rep(c(0.5, NA, 0.7, NA), 4)`

Comment: @CCID I still don't get what you want, is something like the last example from here? http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_hline.html

Comment: I'll edit my question again. I need to plot horizontal lines across each bar, but at different values on each bar. geom_bar() will do this, but using my workround with the NAs, eg using `bars` from the comment above in the code

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I have above, can you point me to changing line type and color on the lines? My attempts at this change the legend

Comment: Edited for lty=2 and custom colors. Legend is still a pain (take into acount you want to put a legend to each of the errorbar calls)